# Can't always view object within a transparent box

Tags: transparency

I have a transparent box with a few objects within it.  Depending on the view, the objects inside are visible and sometimes not.  I'm running Blender v2.82a.  Figure 1 shows the objects visible.  Figure 2 shows one not visible.  The objects inside are also transparent.  Objects outside of the cube seem to always be visible regardless of the view (the red cylinder).  The images suddenly disappear and just as suddenly reappear depending on the viewing angle.[image: Figure 1]

Here the tube on the right is invisible.
[image: Figure 2]

The Shading panel for the box is in Figure 3.[image: Figure 3: Shading Panel]

The Materials panel for the box is in Figure 4.  It has the Blend Mode set to Alpha Blend.  The Shadow Mode setting doesn't seem to matter. [image: Figure 4: Materials]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a technical limitation in Eevee called **Alpha Sorting**.

Unlike Cycles, which uses [ray tracing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_tracing), Eevee is a [rasterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasterisation) engine, which means each triangle that's visible to the camera is transformed into screen space and "rasterized" into a pixel buffer.

[image: rasterization]

(*Image from learnopengl.com*)

When a rasterization engine renders objects with transparency, it has to render triangles furthest from the camera *first*, and progressively render things that are closer. If closer triangles were rendered first, any transparent objects rendered behind it later would be discarded by the **depth test**, which means the engine would think the object is occluded because there's something in front of it. If depth of transparent objects is ignored (an approach some engines use), it can alter the final color, which is also not ideal. The process of determining the order in which triangles need to be rendered is called **Alpha Sorting**.

According to the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/eevee/materials/settings.html#sorting-problem):

> As of now Eevee does not support per-fragment (pixel) sorting or per-triangle sorting. Only per-object sorting is available and is automatically done on all transparent surfaces based on object origin.

What's happening in your case is that the alpha sorting is incorrectly ordering the objects at different angles, causing some to be occluded and thus not render.

---

**As for the fix**, start by enabling `Show Backface` in the material settings. It can resolve a lot of these alpha sorting problems.

If that doesn't work, try messing with the `Backface Culling` setting too, as that can make a difference in certain cases.

You can always switch to Cycles, it doesn't suffer from these limitations.